# How to put dynamic Menu items from databse in MasterLayout.cshtml?

Tags: javascript

I have tried to implement Dynamic menu items in MasterLayout.cshtml

But at the time of creating MasterLayout it doesn't provide option of Select Model like in Normal View..

So, How to add Dynamic Menu in MasterLayout so that it can be displayed in all the Normal Views???

Answer (score 0):

You shoud create a strongly typed PartialView to generate the menu dynamicaly at the MasterLayout. For exemple:

1) Create a an action at the HomeController, as ChildAction, to prevent external access, this will be used only as Menu render:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult MainMenu()
{
    var menu = /*Populate the menu*/;

    return PartialView("_MainMenu", menu);
}
```

2) Create a strongly typed view at Views/Shared named _MainMenu.cshtml for the menu. You should pass a enumeration or something else to create it dynamically.

3) Put the line above at the MasterLayout to render the menu dinamically:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("MainMenu", "Home"); }
```

There's a good example here, for an editable Menu. I recomend you to take a look for get idea about the model structure: [Dynamic Menus in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=811).